# Extracting rows based on a substring in a column using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a  tab seperated vcf file which as a following format

```
#CHROM  POS   REF   ALT       INFO
chr1    111    A    TT;C     AC=0;AN=33
chr1    111    A     G;t     AC=0;AN=100
chr1    111    G     A       AC=110;AN=51
chr2    737    T     Q       AC=99;AN=10003
chr2    888    G     G       AC=100;AN=1636
```

I want to extract lines into a new text file where AC in **INFO** column is greater than 100 so the expected output becomes:

```
#CHROM  POS   REF   ALT  INFO
chr1    111    G     A   AC=110;AN=51
```

The awk command I have so far is:

```
awk 'NR==1 || /AC=[0-9][0-9][0-9]+/ && !/AC=100/'  file.vcf > output.txt
```

However, my file is quite large and it takes a long time to complete. Is there a way to extract it where I specify that AC in $5 (i.e. the info column) should greater than 100. Insights will be appreciated.

Comment: Is the `AC=` field always present in the last column? When it is present, is it always the first field in that column? If the answer is "no" to either of those questions then please [edit] the example in your question to include cases that don't have `AC=` or have it in a different order than first. Similarly if `AC=` can appear in any other column too then add such a case. Oh, and also tell us if any column can contain blanks.

Comment: AC is alway in the last column and AC is always the first column in the last column.

Comment: And there are no blanks in the file.

Comment: Is this actually a valid VCF file? What you show isn't valid: you can't have `;` in the ALT field, those should be `,` and you need the headers as well as at least the genotype field and the missing FILTER and FORMAT fields. If it's a valid VCF there are dedicated tools to deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use awk for this. I mean, you can, but there are better tools. If this is really a valid VCF file, something like this:

```
##fileformat=VCFv4.3
##INFO=<ID=AC,Number=A,Type=Integer,Description="Allele count in genotypes, for each ALT allele, in the same order as listed">
##INFO=<ID=AN,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Total number of alleles in called genotypes">
##FORMAT=<ID=GT,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Genotype">
##contig=<ID=chr1>
##contig=<ID=chr2>
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  foo
chr1    111 .   A   TT,C    100 PASS    AC=0;AN=33  GT  0/1
chr1    111 .   A   G,t 100 PASS    AC=0;AN=100 GT  0/1
chr1    111 .   G   A   100 PASS    AC=110;AN=51    GT  0/1
chr2    737 .   T   Q   100 PASS    AC=99;AN=10003  GT  0/1
chr2    888 .   G   G   100 PASS    AC=100;AN=1636  GT  1/1
```

Then you can use [`bcftools`](https://samtools.github.io/bcftools/bcftools.html):

```
$ bcftools view -i "AC[*]>100" foo.vcf
##fileformat=VCFv4.3
##FILTER=<ID=PASS,Description="All filters passed">
##INFO=<ID=AC,Number=A,Type=Integer,Description="Allele count in genotypes, for each ALT allele, in the same order as listed">
##INFO=<ID=AN,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Total number of alleles in called genotypes">
##FORMAT=<ID=GT,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Genotype">
##contig=<ID=chr1>
##contig=<ID=chr2>
##bcftools_viewVersion=1.16+htslib-1.16
##bcftools_viewCommand=view -i AC[*]>100 foo.vcf; Date=Sat Nov  5 12:40:53 2022
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  foo
chr1    111 .   G   A   100 PASS    AC=110;AN=51    GT  0/1
```

If it isn't a real VCF, and is as you show in your question, you can just do something like this:

```
$ perl -ne '/AC=(\d+)/; print if /^#/ || $1 > 100' foo.notVcf
#CHROM  POS   REF   ALT       INFO
chr1    111    G     A       AC=110;AN=51
```

Comment: Thank you @terdon. This worked.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F'[\t=]' 'NR==1 || ($6+0)>100' file
#CHROM  POS     REF     ALT     INFO
chr1    111     G       A       AC=110;AN=51
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ awk '{split($NF,p,/[=;]/)} NR==1 || p[2]>100' file
#CHROM  POS     REF     ALT     INFO
chr1    111     G       A       AC=110;AN=51
```

Comment: `-F'[\t=]'`: simple and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk '{split($NF,array,";");split(array[1],var,"=")}  NR==1 || var[2]>100'
#CHROM  POS   REF   ALT       INFO
chr1    111    G     A       AC=110;AN=51
```

Comment: What if I have ';' in other columns? I've edited the table so you see what I mean. How can I modify the awk command then?

Comment: @John It would not affect the output as the code is matching on the last column only then splitting it to find the value of `AC`